# Brave browser Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, browser

I am using the Brave browser (Version 0.68.139 Chromium: 77.0.3865.90 (Official version) (64-bit). Ubuntu Mate 18.04.3 kernel 5.2.16. For some time the browser after starting itself turns off. After 1-2 minutes of action. What could be the reason?

Comment: Does this happen on Chromiuim or only Brave? If only Brave that can be misconfiguration or bug in Brave itself.

Comment: I don't use chromium. Brave only. this has been happening for some time.

Comment: You have to check it with Chromium to see if it affects only Brave or Chromium as well. It is simply to install `apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: Chromium works ok. So what's the problem? Uninstalled, cleaned the system, reinstalled and is it still happening?

Comment: Well you can try to remove configuration folder from Home directory and reinstall it from scratch, I had different issues with Brave myself probably is not well polished yet for all Linux distros.